# socket.io : how to get all connected user to a specific room in node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, nodes

its a duplicate question, though i want to ask it.
i want all the username & there socket.id who are currently connected to a room, how to get that,

i tried it with : **var clients = io.sockets.clients('room1');**

here is my code ref

```
// when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
    socket.on('adduser', function(username){
        // store the username in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = username;
        // store the room name in the socket session for this client
    //  socket.myroom = 'room1';
        // add the client's username to the global list
        usernames[username] = username;
        // send client to room 1
        socket.join('room1');
        socket.join('room2');
        // echo to client they've connected
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'room1', 'you have connected to room1');
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'room2', 'you have connected to room2');
        // echo to room 1 that a person has connected to their room
        socket.broadcast.to('room1').emit('updatechat', 'room1', username + ' has connected to this room');
        socket.broadcast.to('room2').emit('updatechat', 'room2', username + ' has connected to this room');
        var clients = io.sockets.clients('room1'); 


        console.log('socket.id :'+ socket.id);

        console.log('projson :'+ clients);
        console.log('projson :'+ clients.socket.id);
        console.log('projson :'+ clients.socket);

    });
```

here is the log

```
debug: set heartbeat interval for client lhF85vZH16MLuMxyuIFH
debug: client authorized for 
debug: websocket writing 1::
debug: websocket writing 5:::{"name":"updatechat","args":["room1","you have connected to room1"]}
debug: websocket writing 5:::{"name":"updatechat","args":["room2","you have connected to room2"]}
debug: broadcasting packet
debug: websocket writing 5:::{"name":"updatechat","args":["room1","p3 has connected to this room"]}
debug: broadcasting packet
debug: websocket writing 5:::{"name":"updatechat","args":["room2","p3 has connected to this room"]}
socket.id :lhF85vZH16MLuMxyuIFH
**projson :[object Object],[object Object]**
projson :undefined
projson :undefined
```

how to get socketid & user name , any help will be appreciated , 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

try

```
console.log(io.sockets.manager.rooms)
```

this will give you something like this:

```
{
    "room1":[socketidOfUser1,socketidOfUser2],
    "room2":[socketidOfUser3,socketidOfUser4],
}
```

see if this gives the information you need

Comment: it shows { '': [ 'CrkuKO07OmUXdqWx-En8', 'piCYuc7WY0P8n015-En9' ],
  '/room1': [ 'CrkuKO07OmUXdqWx-En8', 'piCYuc7WY0P8n015-En9' ],
  '/room2': [ 'CrkuKO07OmUXdqWx-En8', 'piCYuc7WY0P8n015-En9' ] } when 2 user connect to both rooms ,

Comment: @pitu yeah what exactly do you want?

Comment: i want the username associated to each socket, i want private messaging to 1 of them

Answer (score 0):

To get the socket ids:

```
Object.keys(io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms[roomName].sockets)
```